# mm qcamera daemon draining battery on S5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-5

My s5 phone is facing a problem due to mm qcamera daemon bug since 05 November 2014. How can I fix it?

I have tried restarting and deleting the cache but that did not work.

Comment: Did you try to froze or disable the app? (Ideal thing would be delete that drainy app)

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. What you can do is delete all camera using programs and ir games. Ex. Skype, viber, ym. What happens is the auto shut off codeing is not releasing the camera function shut off which is the program called mm-qcamera daemon. Currently there is no fix and no set plans for s5. Googles response has been that its your phones carrier problem until they recieve more issues with this problem. I have turned phone off, restarted,  as well as took battery out. It comes and goes and is a pain to get turned off. My fiancées phone became so hot that she couldnt hold the phone in her hand. Use a task killer to help close all tasks before restarting phone.  Clear your cache, btw didnt work for me...If all this doesnt work, sell your phone to a sucker and by something non android. Just so you know the daemon program is in the andriods operating system. There is no easy way to remove the program from the hardware. A system reset will get rid of it that time but, Ive done it a dozen times or so and the problem still comes back.                    Just a fyi.... nexus phone had same problem. Android had an update, a fix this issue specifically, and it didnt work on all nexus phones. I believe its just a lost cause and shows you what android and Google think about you.   Here.... I found this link.. seems some carriers will replace it.http://m.androidcentral.com/some-users-report-galaxy-s5-camera-failures

Answer (score 1):

In my case, problem was Snapchat.
After I freeze Snapchat everything back to normal.
I also use Viber and Facebook messenger

Answer (score 0):

My fix is to use an app called [D-vasive Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.DvasivePro) that has the function to deny access to the camera. No other app is then able to constantly connect to the camera. The downside is that you are not able to use your camera to take pictures. You can of course allow access to the camera for a short while when you take your pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I had the same problem. My problem started after I updated whatsapp and maps apps. I disabled maps updates, reinstaled whatsupp but before that I runned some program memory cleaner, which I used and deleted. After that I cleared cache memory. Now everything works perfectly.